# Cant get app access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im desperately trying to get the app access token and failing miserably.
Perhaps someone code help

The first way i am trying to get is below :

```
try {
    $access_t = $facebook->api(
        '/oauth/access_token', 'get', array(
            'client_id'     => $app_id,  
            'client_secret' => $app_secret, 
            'redirect_uri'  => $canvas_page_url
        )
    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

I get the error "AuthException: An unknown error has occurred." I confess im not sure what url i should be using for $canvas_page_url So i have used my apps.facebook.com/appname url

Any ideas?

The second way i am trying is :

```
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
    . 'client_id=' . $app_id
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
    . '&grant_type=client_credentials';
```

And although this does return a access token i am reading that in fact its wron g... Not long enough?

```
result = 248119721897385|LvWcoYbWu2lQlkEN0HDOeIupSqs
```

Any ideas on this would be really appreciated as its been doing my head in for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd method returns what looks like Facebooks new encrypted access token and is probably just fine.  Have you tested it out.  https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={your access token}

I'm guessing it will work just fine for things the app token has access to do.  For some operations you'll need other types of tokens like the user token.

Comment: try {
      $me = $facebook->api('/me', 'post', array('access_token' => $access_token));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      echo $e;
}

Comment: /me may not be accessible via the app token because of the content.  From a browser try something like https://graph.facebook.com/mgmgrand/events?access_token={your token}.  Testing the url in a browser has been my fastest method of testing certain tokens.  Be sure to use https when passing a token to the graph